# Does Unity Tweak Tool still have support for selecting default applications?

Tags: gui, default-programs, unity-tweak-tool

I read that the default applications can be set in Unity Tweak Tool. But where is it, which panel?
Has the project stopped giving support for this functionality ?

Please add **screenshots** for users to see and also your Unity Tweak Tool **version**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity Tweak Tool (currently version 0.0.6) never had an option to select default applications.

But Unity Tweak Tool has a lot of other options to customize the Unity desktop environment.

[image]

You still can select the default applications from the system settings application ... of course.

[image]

In case you meant Ubuntu Tweak - this tool seems to not be maintained since a long time.

The last release was version 0.8 for Ubuntu 14.04 - available in [Ubuntu Tweak Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Comment: Yes I got confused, the program I read about was http://ubuntu-tweak.com/